# How did the square root get its shape?

Tags: notation, math-history

I was wondering when in history did people start use the $\sqrt{}$ sign for square root, what did they use before, and why this curious nomenclature is adopted.

Comment: If you're not looking for crazy amounts of information, there's always [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#History)!

Comment: FYI, here's [a discussion about a more logical notation for exponents, roots, and logs](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1158802/3157).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can find information about the history of the usage in Jeff Miller's page here: [Earliest Uses of Symbols of Operation](http://jeff560.tripod.com/operation.html).

Quoted:

> Square root. The first use of a
>   capital R with a diagonal line was in
>   1220 by Leonardo of Pisa in Practica
>   geometriae, where the symbol meant
>   "square root" (Cajori vol. 1, page
>   90).
>
> The radical symbol first appeared in
>   1525 in Die Coss by Christoff Rudolff
>   (1499-1545). He used the symbol [image]
>   (without the vinculum) for square
>   roots. He did not use indices to
>   indicate higher roots, but instead
>   modified the appearance of the radical
>   symbol for higher roots.
>
> It is often suggested that the origin
>   of the modern radical symbol is that
>   it is an altered letter r, the first
>   letter in the word radix. This is the
>   opinion of Leonhard Euler in his
>   Institutiones calculi differentialis
>   (1775). However, Florian Cajori,
>   author of A History of Mathematical
>   Notations, argues against this theory.
>
> In 1637 Rene Descartes used [image], adding
>   the vinculum to the radical symbol La
>   Geometrie (Cajori vol. 1, page 375).

Comment: Cajori should always be everybody's first stop when looking for notation history.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is that the Arabic letter jeem ج which is the first letter in the Arabic Jathr جذر meaning root, Algebra on the other hand was invented by a muslim scholar which is Arabic word for al-jabr "restoration"