# Is there a collection of alternative mathematical notation? (Semi-soft Question)

Tags: soft-question, notation, recreational-mathematics

I'm interested in alternative systems of notation for mathematics. I've often heard how mathematical notation is illogical, inconsistent, filled with *grandfather clauses* that serve no purpose, and suggests deprecated ideas (e.g .the $\rm{dx}$ of the integral and derivative).

It seems reasonable to suppose someone has tried to come up with some alternative notation.

My interest in this is mostly curiosity. I'm very interested in what people have come up with to rectify the perceived faults. I vaguely remember seeing a link to some alternative notation of logarithms, but I seem to have lost it.

I know that using highly non-standard notation is a bad idea for many reasons. I highly doubt I will use it.

Also, I don't mean *good* notation or even *consistent* notation. I'm just interested in something different, preferably a lot of it, and in one place.

I'm labeling this as a soft question, but I'm not really looking for suggestions or discussions for alternative notation. I just want a good source(s).

Comment: Maybe you were thinking of this posting for logs http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30046/alternative-notation-for-exponents-logs-and-roots ? Regards

Comment: Nope, it was actually something else, though I've seen this too. What I remember involved squiggly lines, kind of like a square root.

Comment: One "folklore" alternative notation is write functions in postfix notation, like $xf$ or $(x+3)f$ instead of $f(x+3)$. This way the compositions are naturally read left to right: $(x)fgh$ instead of $h(g(f(x)))$. (NB: This is not to say that LTR is more natural than RTL, just that the rest of mathematical formulas are read LTR). With linear operators, for which parentheses are often omitted,  one could write things like $2xAB$, with linearity (or at least homogeneity) built-in. I don't have any references, unfortunately.

Comment: Attend a course taught by an analyst. I guarantee you'll see weird and inconsistent notations.

Comment: @GregRos Squiggly lines remind me of Frege's *Begriffsschrift,* which is more or less unreadable ...

Comment: @GregRos: Here is a somewhat recent [**Survey of Notation**](http://kwarc.info/publications/papers/kw1_notationSurvey.pdf) and has some links for others who have tried. There is even a book *A History of Mathematical Notations: Vol. I & II* by Florian Cajorion on the matter, but I think people define, invent and use what they want and it has caused lots of headaches for us all! Interesting question - regards

Comment: In group theory pretty much everything has at some point been written $G_j$ or $G^j$, where $j$ can be an integer, an element, or a subgroup.  Because of this a lot of things have two different forms, e.g. $G_x$ vs $\text{Stab}_G(x)$, $H_G$ vs $\text{core}_G(H)$, etc.

Comment: I don't know if this counts as "alternative" enough: In the preface of *[Structure and Interpretation of Classical Mechanics](http://mitpress.mit.edu/SICM/)*, Sussman and Wisdom reject the traditional notation for the Euler-Lagrange equations, $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial\dot q_i}-\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial q_i}=0$, as ambiguous and inconsistent, opting instead for a computer-algebra-like notation $D(\partial_2 L\circ\Gamma[q])-\partial_1 L\circ\Gamma[q]=0$. All the math in the rest of the book is written in this style.

Comment: @Amzoti That comment looks like pretty good material for an answer. Could you consider converting it? Thank you!

Comment: @rschwieb: Okay, done. Thanks for the suggestion. I wish there was a way for users to accept comments in order to remove what appear to be open questions. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti Great! Actually I was thinking of your second comment's content too :) If you have time, you might add that also.

Comment: as someone who has had a great deal of trouble learning anything beyond basic pre-cal, but has some success learning math concepts in a programming context, this question greatly interests me. i'd be curious whether anyone has tried making a different notation just for the sake of being different, to try and capture some minds that don't pick up well on traditional math notation.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a somewhat recent [*Survey of Notation*](https://kwarc.info/people/cmueller/papers/ntn-techreport.pdf) and has some links for others who have tried.

There is even a book A History of Mathematical Notations: Vol. I & II by Florian Cajori on on the matter, but I think people define, invent and use what they want and it has caused lots of headaches for us all!

Lastly, you can also find some samples in this MSE posting [Alternative notation for exponents, logs and roots?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30046/alternative-notation-for-exponents-logs-and-roots)

This was added from the comment I made above to close this question out per request.

Comment: Don't forget the references in the other comment of yours!

Comment: @rschwieb: Thanks - I totally forgot about those, but added and cleaned up. Thanks! Regards

Comment: Thanks for converting the comment!+1 [Visit us](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141/the-crusade-of-answers) someday if you have some time to spare.

Comment: A late gem, to the rescue...+1

Comment: @ShuhaoCao: Thank you. I may pay a visit and see what is going on. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti Yes, indeed, all is well. TGIF is almost here (aka POET Day! ;)

Comment: (survey of notation) link broken as of Sun 2016-12-11T13:31:40 https://kwarc.info/publications/papers/kw1_notationSurvey.pdf

Comment: @Amzoti could this, perhaps, be the broken link you referenced? kwarc.info/people/cmueller/papers/ntn-techreport.pdf If so, perhaps it could be edited in.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to see  what *unambiguous* math notation looks like, look at an application where it *has* to be unambiguous: the input languages for proof-checkers ([Coq](http://coq.inria.fr), [Mizar](http://mizar.org/)) and computer algebra systems ([Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), [Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com/products/Maple/), [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/)). Mathematica (and possibly also the other linked CASs with which I'm less familiar) supports WYSIWYG input mostly resembling traditional textbook notation, so it might be an especially good example.

Comment: See also TeX...

Comment: [Metamath](http://metamath.org) is a closely related example.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting list covering notations in several domains is [Notes on notation and thought](https://github.com/hypotext/notation).

Recently, I also stumbled upon G. Spencer-Brown [Laws of Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_Form).  I recommend the introductory text from L. H. Kauffman [Laws of Form - An Exploration in Mathematics and Foundations](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/Laws.pdf).