# Isn't square root a bit like Log()?

Tags: logarithms, arithmetic, exponentiation, radicals

I want start by saying that my math skills aren't great and I'm trying to learn.

I took a look at square root.

Squaring the number means `x^2`.

And if I understood the square root correctly it does a bit inverse of squaring a number and gets back the `x`.

I had a friend tell me a while ago that `Log()` is also opposite of exponent, wouldn't that mean that square root is like a variant of Log() that only inverse a squared number?

Comment: the inverse of $x^2$ is a the square root, the inverse of $2^x$ is the (base 2) logarithm. The inverse of $x^a$ is the $a$-th root, the inverse of $a^x$ is the (base a) logarithm.

Comment: In a certain light, yes: roots and logs are kinda the same. They both look at the relation $a^b=c$ and ask *"If I know one of the numbers on the left (and the number on the right), then what's the other number?"* ... When you know $b$ (and $c$)  and seek $a$, you get what we call "the $b$-th root of $c$"; when you know $a$ (and $c$) and seek $b$, you get what we call "the base-$a$ logarithm of $c$". ... Interestingly, [a popular question (from 2011!) on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30046/409) asked for ideas about how to make this interplay clearer in the notation we use.

Comment: @JensRenders Of course it is. Here is a link, but you being a master's that link ought not to be needed: http://www.columbia.edu/itc/sipa/math/logarithms.html

Comment: @imranfat You worded it confusingly. I understand what you mean now because of your answer, but It seemed like you where saying that a logaritmic function is an exponential function. what you meant was that the output of a logarithmic function is naturally the input of an exponential function. It is important to word it better because using your language, any number is an exponent.

Comment: @imranfat A logarithm isn't an exponent, just like how a cube root isn't a cube.

Comment: @imranfat (When you phrase it the way you did, it strongly suggests *exponential function*, which it's of course not. I think you know this, though.)

Answer (score 27):

It might be best to answer with some examples.

- The number $\log_7 23$ answers the question $7^{?} = 23$.
- The number $\sqrt[7]{23}$ answers the question $?^7 = 23$.

As you can see, these are different questions.

Some further points:

- When we write $\log$, this is short for $\log_{10}$. So the number $\log 23$ answers the question $10^? = 23$.
- When we write $\sqrt{\phantom{x}}$, this is short for $\sqrt[2]{\phantom{x}}$. So the number $\sqrt{23}$ answers the question $?^2 = 23$.