# Log question: Is there any way to manipulate the following equation to get a specific outcome?

Tags: logarithms

I've been working at this for hours. I want to know if it's even possible for the equation $n=(\frac{3}2)^k$ to be manipulated to become $n^{log_23}$.

Edit: What about $(3/2)^{log_2n}$ to become $n^{log_23}$?

Comment: That second expression isn’t an equation so it’s not entirely clear what you mean. We have $k = log_{3/2} n$, though.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: As for your edit, in general we have $x^{\log_b y} = b^{(\log_b x)(\log_b y)} = y^{\log_b x}$ (this is probably the most bizarre and least intuitive log identity), which gives $n^{\log_2 3} = 3^{\log_2 n}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Wouldn't we get $^{log_2(3/2)}$ instead of $^{log_23}$ since $x$ is $3/2$?

Comment: You've written down two numbers which are almost but not quite equal so there are two identities. One is $n^{\log_2 3} = 3^{\log_2 n}$ and the other is $(3/2)^{\log_2 n} = n^{\log_2 (3/2)}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. You've actually helped me a ton with that rule you showed me!!

Comment: You might find [this 3Blue1Brown video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sULa9Lc4pck) interesting. Or the [Math Exchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30046/alternative-notation-for-exponents-logs-and-roots) that inspired it.