# Reflective/Inversion Symmetry of Triangle of Powers

Tags: soft-question, logarithms, exponentiation, radicals, symmetry

I was fascinated by [this 3b1b video](https://youtu.be/sULa9Lc4pck?t=418) about the Triangle of Powers and was tinkering around with it myself. Specifically, I noticed (after the timestamped part) that if I reflect the triangle while keeping the pivot vertex unchanged, then the numbers in the other vertices stay in the same place but change to their operative inverse.

For example, say the triangle has $a$ in the lower left, $b$ in the top, and $c$ in the lower right.

If I reflect the triangle over the $b$ vertex, then the lower left becomes $\frac{1}{a}$ and lower right becomes $\frac{1}{c}$.

$$\begin{align*}
{}_a&\overset{b}{\triangle}_c &&\iff &{}_{(1/a)}&\overset{b}{\triangle}_{(1/c)}\\
a^b &= c &&\iff &\left(\frac 1a\right)^b &= \frac 1c
\end{align*}$$

Similarly, if I reflect it over the $a$ vertex, then the top becomes $-b$ (since the assigned operation is a $+$) and the lower right becomes $\frac{1}{c}$. The same happens if I reflect over the $c$ vertex.

$$\begin{align*}
&\ldots\iff &{}_{a}&\overset{-b}{\triangle}_{(1/c)} &&\iff &{}_{(1/a)}&\overset{-b}{\triangle}_{c}\\
&\ldots\iff &a^{-b} &= \frac 1c &&\iff &\left(\frac 1a\right)^{-b} &= c
\end{align*}$$

BUT, if I attempt to do the opposite i.e. swap the other two vertices while making sure they're unchanged, then it only works for the reflection over the $b$ vertex. Specifically, the intuition I came up with is that since the other two vertices have the multiplication operation assigned to them, if I keep them unchanged then the pivot 'inherits' the operative inverse of the other two.

$$\begin{align*}
{}_a&\overset{b}{\triangle}_c &&\iff &{}_{c}&\overset{1/b}{\triangle}_{a}\\
a^b &= c &&\iff &c^{1/b} &= a
\end{align*}$$

Naturally, this intuition breaks apart when trying to apply it to the other ways of reflecting the triangle. Since, you know, how is the pivot supposed to inherit the operative inverse of  the other two vertices if those vertices have different operations? One might think 'just make it become the negative reciprocal' but as we know, it doesn't work like that.

I'm looking for a better intuition for this, if this is at all possible. At first glance, it feels like there should be a way to make this work, but as 3b1b said [here](https://youtu.be/sULa9Lc4pck?t=401): "The asymmetries in the notation correspond to the actual asymmetries in the numerical relationship of $a^b=c$ itself" i.e. the fact that it is taught as $a$ being multiplied with itself $b$ number of times to get $c$.

It there a way to make this work or is this all just in vain?

Comment: Hi, I tried to include some triangles of power in the question. Please check if I understood your text correctly, as I am not sure about the "reflect" operation while the positions of $a,b,c$ don't move (unlike in the video).

Comment: [Link to the original answer of the triangle notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/165225/89922).

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you’re looking for?  You’ve described three symmetries related to keeping one of the corners constant, where you can do two of the following to the other two (flip bottom left, negate top, flip bottom right).

Comment: There’s the fun fact that if you invert the top, then it switches the bottom two.

Comment: Tbh, it might be better notation to remove the bottom line - there’s more symmetry between the bottom two than there is between the top and the others. You can’t really rotate the triangle of power.

Comment: @peterwhy Yes, that would be correct. I wasn't sure how to type them in latex, so thanks for that. I've also added another one for more clarity.